# AVPlayer Pause/Rewind Live Stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I currently am using AVPlayer to play a live video stream which works fine. However, I am trying to add the ability to "rewind" the stream to a certain point, lets say within a 2 minute window.

Is it as simple as using the seekTo method, where I calculate the current time vs the time to jump back?

How does AVPlayer actually work in this manner, does it store the stream on the filesystem and read from that?

This is how I am approaching the problem:

```
- (void) rewindStream:(float)time
{
    NSLog(@"Seeking...");
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) + time, self.player.currentTime.timescale);
    [self.player.currentItem seekToTime:cmTime];
}
```

Currently, it seeks, but it doesnt seem as though it jumps back. It seems like it just refreshes the stream.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: How are you doing this now in code?

Comment: Check my edit. Example call: [self rewindStream:-30.0]